# Twitter authentication using similar to Vine dialog in Android

Tags: android, twitter, oauth

I want to make an authentication dialog similar to Vine: [image: twitter authenticationin vine]

Thought it can be done using [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html). But it gives me entirely different dialog. I suppose Vine is using some private intent that shows this dialog.

Are there any public/non-public APIs for Twitter Android app that gives this dialog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twitter Auth is seems like not well documented.

You need to launch activity `com.twitter.android.AuthorizeAppActivity` in `com.twitter.android` package with following extras:

- `ck` — consumer key
- `cs` — consumer secret

and get result back. In result bundle you will get following extras:

- `tk` — access token
- `ts` — token secret
- `screen_name` — looks like it is screen name
- `user_id` — same here

You must hold `com.twitter.android.permission.AUTH_APP` to start this activity.